# writing my C++ code in C language

Tags: c++, c

I have written a C++ code and I want to rewrite it in C. I don't know how to use printf instead of cout (line 6)

```
int a[3][3], j, i, n=1, s=0, r, c=0;
    for (i=0 ; i<=3 ; i++)
    {
        for(j=0 ; j<=3 ; j++)
        {
            cout<< "a[" << i << "][" << j << "] = ";
            cin>> a[i][j];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hint: `printf` and `scanf`

Comment: i don't know how can i use printf

Comment: Add spaces in your code man. Nobody likes to read other peoples' code with no spaces.

Comment: SO isn't a translation service. Nor is it a manual on `printf`. There are plenty of `printf` references and examples out there.

Comment: aha ok, thanks , I will write it better and show again.

Comment: Post your attempts at using printf that go wrong and you'll get more help. It's something like `printf("a[%d][%d] = ", i, j);`

Comment: @Mahdi There's a whole internet in front of you, *and* the documentation on your own computer, *and* a multitude of books to choose from. It's very easy to find out if you don't know.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove unused variable declarations then the code could look like:

```
int a[3][3];
int i, j;

for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
{
    for ( j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
    {
        printf( "a[%d][%d] = ", i, j );
        scanf( "%d", &a[i][j] );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer you let him work out the usage of `printf` and `scanf` by himself. Would have been some good learning experience ...